# a object to object mapper compatible on Android

Tags: android, object, mapper

I'm looking for an object to object mapper for Android. It's all about an automation of Java Bean to Java Bean copy so that each field with a name xyz will match a field xyz in another class. I've tried already each of those in Java
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/java-object-to-object-mapper.html

But none is Android compilable, do you have any ideas what to try?

Comment: you'll have to iterate the class with reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using this , a mapper for pojos

https://github.com/txusballesteros/android-transformer

Comment: It has some limitations. Check open issues (7 at this moment). Lacks List, generics, inheritance support.

Answer (score 1):

I used http://modelmapper.org in some projects. Quite flexible. See the [getting-started](http://modelmapper.org/getting-started/) for more info.
Just add this in your build.gradle:

`compile 'org.modelmapper:modelmapper:0.7.4'`