# Android Bean Mapper Library

Tags: android, mapping, javabeans, pojo

Is there any Android library for Bean/POJO mapping?

As I've already found out there are a lot of Java libraries for such mapping. Among them: Dozer, ModelMapper etc. But they have issues with Android.

Comment: Try using Jackson ObjectMapper

Comment: @karthikvishnukumar I don't need JSON serialization/deserialization. I need a mapping between objects.

Comment: yes you can map with the use of jackson ObjectMapper

Comment: @karthikvishnukumar Thanks. Will have a look at this library.

Comment: Check this one <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784031/a-object-to-object-mapper-compatible-on-android>